# WPF - Dynamically rearrange control hierarchy

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, graph-algorithm

How is it possible to dynamically fill a container? Let's say to fill a big circle with small circles, recursively. Just fill the space fine.

I would like to use it for data hierarchy display.

To make it clear:

[image]

Comment: interesting question. obviously, you'll have to implement something yourself using Canvas. I've bookmarked this question so that I can hopefully see what you come up with.

Comment: @Mykola Bogdiuk: UniformGrid is too "dumb", I would like to draw controls smart&aesthetic.

Comment: I believe there's no control in WPF (without external libraries) that can fit its children inside Ellipse or any custom shape (without cropping of course). You may create your own - derive it from `FrameworkElement`, override `OnRender()`, `MeasureOverride()` and `ArrangeOverride()`.

Comment: @Mykola Bogdiuk: thank you. I'll try it combined with Graph#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something off the shelf, have a look at Graph#

http://graphsharp.codeplex.com/

videos here:

- Simple usage scenario
  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VTbuvkaPGxE
- Data Visualization with Graph#
  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=agDPDzqB4o0&feature=related

It does dynamic graph layout and is fairly easy to use. There are a choice of layout algorithms [see sample app] each of which are configurable.

however filling until an area is "full" is not something that'll work out of the box. Although you could for example create a graph, lay it out & then measure the ratio between the size of a vertex and the size of the whole graph, then add or remove vertexes until you hit upon your desired density. I would hazard you could pretty quickly by trial and error come up with a quick and dirty forumula between the size of canvas to fill & the number of vertexes you should add.

Note that you can customise the vertex templates pretty easily to be any kind of data [this is standard wpf but Graph# specific examples can be found on http://graphsharp.codeplex.com/discussions ]

if you wanted to code your own layout you might like to have a look at some of the techniques Graph# use... for example a dynamic zoom component the source for which is available here: http://wpfextensions.codeplex.com/

hope that helps a little

Comment: thank you, it's a good starting point. I'll refresh my question after some tests.